# $W_2(\mu_t,\mu_s)=\sqrt{|t-s|}d(x,y)$ for $\mu_t:=(1-t)\delta_x+t\delta_y$

Tags: optimal-transport

I would like to show that for the curves $[0,1]\ni t\mapsto \mu_t:=(1-t)\delta_x+t\delta_y$ we have $$W_2(\mu_t,\mu_s)=\sqrt{|t-s|}d(x,y)$$ where $W(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the $2$-Wasserstein distance.

My attempt : Using the convexity of $W_2^2$ in both variables and the fact that $W(\delta_x,\delta_y)=d(x,y)$ and $d(x,x)=d(y,y)=0$ we get that
$$W_2^2(\mu_t,\mu_s)=W_2^2((1-t)\delta_x+t\delta_y,(1-s)\delta_x+s\delta_y)\le (1-t)sW_2^2(\delta_x,\delta_y)+t(1-s)W_2^2(\delta_y,\delta_x)=((1-t)s+t(1-s))d(y,x)$$ but I cannot conclude.

Comment: Try to think about what the set of couplings looks like in that two-point situation. I claim it's just a one-parameter family of measures. Therefore, calculating $W$ will boil down to a much simpler optimization problem.

Comment: I am not sure how you do it. My thoughts are that any plan should be of the form $\alpha_{xx}\delta_{\{x,x\}}+\alpha_{xy}\delta_{\{x,y\}}$+$\alpha_{yx}\delta_{\{y,x\}}+\alpha_{y,y}\delta_{\{y,y\}}$ and projecting the two marginals and setting $\alpha:=\alpha_{xx}$ I get by identification of coefficients that the plan has the form $\alpha\delta_{\{x,x\}}+(1-t-\alpha)\delta_{\{x,y\}}+(1-s-\alpha)\delta_{\{y,x\}}+(s-1+t+\alpha)\delta_{\{y,y\}}$ which seems to have 3 parameters.

Comment: @roi_saumon You only have one free parameter for the optimization, the values of $s$ and $t$ are fixed by the marginals.